# flutter/dart - How to group a list of datetimes by month / week

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create some expenses charts from a list and would like to know how I can group the data by month/week.

Input:

```
List<Expense>;
Expense({
    required this.dateTime,
    required this.amount,
  });
```

The output I would like to achieve:

```
[
   //December
   [
   Expense1,
   Expense2,
   Expense3,
   etc
   ],
  //November
  [
   Expense4,
   Expense5,
   Expense6,
   etc
   ], 
   //October
   ...
],
```

How can I get the same result but for weeks?

```
[
   //This week
   [
       //Monday
       [
         Expense1,
         Expense2,
         Expense3,
         etc
       ],
      //Tuesday
      [
         Expense4,
         Expense5,
         Expense6,
         etc
      ],
      ....
   ],
   //Previous week
   ....
],
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
  Map<int, Map<int, List<Expense>>> groupExpensesByWeek() {
    var finalList = Map<int, Map<int, List<Expense>>>();
    var weeksList = groupBy(_expenses!, (Expense obj) => weekNumber(obj.dateTime)); //group the expenses by weeks

    weeksList.forEach((key, value) {
      var listofWeeks = groupBy(value, (Expense obj) => obj.dateTime.weekday); //group the expenses by days

      finalList.addEntries([MapEntry(key, listofWeeks)]); //add map of days to weeks map
    });

    return finalList;
  }

  Map<int, List<Expense>> groupExpensesByMonth() {
    var monthList = groupBy(_expenses!,
        (Expense obj) => int.parse('${obj.dateTime.year}${obj.dateTime.month}')); //group the expenses by year+month: 202210

    return monthList;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
List<Expense> expenses;

Map<String,List<Expense>> sortedExpenses;

for(int i=1;i<=12;i++){
List<Expense> newExpenses;
expenses.forEach(var expense){
 if(expense.dateTime.month==i){
    newExpenses.add(expense);
 }
}
sortedExpenses[i]=newExpenses;
}
```